# AngularJS with Rails 3.1 - trouble loading angular-seed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I've been playing around with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/#/) - which is a kick-ass front end framework by the way.

Today I tried to incorporate the angular-seed starter app (found here:  https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) into a currently existing Rails 3.1.3 application.

Had a few issues getting the demo code - here: http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/tutorial - to work in the asset pipeline, so just for testing purposes I put them into the public folder - old school style.

I followed the tutorial and had all of my views, controllers, services set up correctly.  However, when I included the js files at the bottom of my index page:

```
<script src="angular/app/lib/angular/angular.js" ng:autobind></script>
<script src="angular/app/js/services.js"></script>
<script src="angular/app/js/controllers.js"></script>
```

... none of the controllers would work.  I would get the `{{ model.property }}` tags within my templates instead of the actual output.

No Javascript errors in Chrome's dev tools - and network and resources showed all expected files loaded properly.

I thought that maybe I had overlooked something in my code, but when I looked at the developers guide, there is a link to angular's cdn:

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-0.9.19.min.js" ng:autobind></script>
```

Just for the heck of it, I replaced my local angular.js script call with the cdn, and suddenly everything was working as expected.

I double checked, to make sure that I was loading the local copy from the proper directory, and I was - it's the standard directory that comes with the angular-seed file.  This file was also showing as a resource that was downloaded properly.

**Anyone have ideas on why the cdn worked but the local copy would not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular-seed uses AngularJS 1.0.0rc5 (currently) which is incompatible with 0.9.19. Check out how the seed app is wired. (e.g. remove ng:autobind and add ng:app or ng-app to the html tag in your layout template).

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip - I missed the changes in the new docs.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using an old version: You want to read this: http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/guide/dev_guide.bootstrap.auto_bootstrap

What you should be doing is using the new version, and the docs are here: http://docs-next.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.bootstrap.auto_bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you're missing a double-quote in your first script reference.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for looking.  That's actually a typo on my part here.  The quotes are there in my app.  I'll fix it up top to prevent any confusion.